# Python code patterns: elegant way of trying different methods until one suceeds?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to extract informations from an HTML page, like its last modification date, in a context where there are more than one way of declaring it, and those ways use non-uniform data (meaning a simple loop over fetched data is not possible).

The ugly task is as follow:

```py
def get_date(html):
  date = None
  # Approach 1
  time_tag = html.find("time", {"datetime": True})
  if time_tag:
    date = time_tag["datetime"]
  if date:
    return date

  # Approach 2
  mod_tag = html.find("meta", {"property": "article:modified_time", "content": True})
  if mod_tag:
    date = mod_tag["content"]
  if date:
    return date
  
  # Approach 3
  div_tag = html.find("div", {"class": "dateline"})
  if div_tag:
    date = div_tag.get_text()
  if date:
    return date
  
  # Approach n
  # ...

  return date
```

I wonder if Python doesn't have some concise and elegant way of achieving this through a `while" logic, in order to run fast, be legible and maintenance-friendly:

```py
def method_1(html):
  test = html.find("time", {"datetime": True})
  return test["datetime"] if test else None

def method_2(html):
  test = html.find("meta", {"property": "article:modified_time", "content": True})
  return test["content"] if test else None

def method_3(html):
  test = html.find("div", {"class": "dateline"})
  return test.get_text() if test else None

...

def get_date(html):
  date = None
  bag_of_methods = [method_1, method_2, method_3, ...]

  i = 0
  while not date and i < len(bag_of_methods):
    date = bag_of_methods[i](html)
    i += 1

  return date
```

I can make that work right now by turning each approach from the first snippet in a function, append all functions to the `bag_of_methods` iterable and run them all until one works.

However, those functions would be 2 lines each and will not be reused later in the program, so it just seems like it's adding more lines of code and polluting the namespace for nothing.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: To avoid polluting the namespace, you could put that in a class, or in a separate module.

Comment: Then it's even more code overhead for non-reusable code.

Comment: At least if you have multiple methods, then unit testing them becomes trivial.

Comment: If most methods look the same way, you can abstract out the varying strings and the dict as parameter(s) of the function call and iterate through a list of these parameters and call the function for each parameter set.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Methods don't look the same, I updated the example to show it.

Comment: That's an awkward `while` loop. `for m in bag_of_methods: if (date := m(html)) ...: return date`

Comment: "However, those functions would be 2 lines each and will not be reused later in the program, so it just seems like it's adding more lines of code and polluting the namespace for nothing." to avoid polluting the name space, you can just define them inside `def_date`. Who cares about "more lines"?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the namespace clean, you can define the `method_x` functions inside your `get_date`:

```
def get_date(HTML):

  def method_1(HTML):
    test = html.find("time", {"datetime": True})
    return test["datetime"] if test else None

  def method_2(HTML):
    test = html.find("meta", {"property": "article:modified_time", "content": True})
    return test["content"] if test else None

  date = None
  bag_of_methods = [method_1, method_2, ...]
  #...
```

I also feel hinky when I see a `while` loop looping over a defined sequence, so I'd be tempted to rewrite with a `for` and a `break`.  Also, beware that certain types can evaluate to `False` in a boolean context, so you might want to re-write the escape condition using `is None`:

```
date = None

for test in bag_of_methods:
    date = test(html)
    if date is not None:
        break
```

Also, you can utilize the short-circuiting property of `or`:

```
date = method_1(html) or method_2(html) or method_3(html)
if date:
  return date
else:
  return None
```

Execution will go from left to right, and will stop as soon as something returns a value that evaluates to `True` - although this falls into the same trap if one of your dates somehow evaluates to `False`

Comment: For better modifiability, the function could take a list of functions to be tried. And loop over that. The disadvantage of the `or` chaining is that one has to write it down. While the `for` loop with `break` can handle any amount of functions in a specific order.

since `date` is either a value or None, just do `return date` instead of if-else at the end.

Comment: ```def get_date(html, methods={method_1, method_2, ...)):
    for method in methods:
        date = method(html)
        if date is not None:
            return date```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something reusable:

```py
class CallChain:
    def __init__(self, *methods):
        self.methods = methods
        
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for method in self.methods:
            result = method(*args, **kwargs)
            if result is not None:
                return result
        return False
```

To use it:

```py
get_date = CallChain(method_1, method_2, method_3)
date = get_date(html)
```

You can use this class for other method chains as well.

A different implementation of this idea is to use enclosure:

```py
def call_chain(*methods):
    def call_it(*args, **kwargs):
        for method in methods:
            result = method(*args, **kwargs)
            if result is not None:
                return result
        return False
    return call_it
```

To use it:

```py
get_date = call_chain(method_1, method_2, method_3)
date = get_date(html)
```